# Apache Spark building on Amazon EC2 error with Spark-Maven-Plugin failure

Tags: java, scala, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently building Apache Spark on Amazon EC2 linux VMs, following [these instructions](http://from%20spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).

The tools I am using for the building:

> apache-maven: 3.2.5;
>
> scala: 2.10.4;
>
> zinc: 0.3.5.3;
>
> Java: jdk1.7.0_79
>
> Linux 32bits

This error message is raised:

```
Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) on project spark-core_2.10: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:testCompile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

The website suggests that the error could be caused by a plugin failure, but provides no details. What is the problem? Is there an approach I can take to resolve the error?

Comment: Did you try -e or -X for more debugging?

Comment: yep I did, it only pops out more error info tho which is tough to track, too much to include it in the comment put it there:

Comment: @bcxuezhe39 can you post your pom file ? the link to **these instructions** seems broken

Comment: Sorry didn't see your common in time. It is kinda strange that after trying the same operation on google cluster, the building is successful. Still don't know why building on ec2 doesn't work yet. Is memory a possible issue? (while google instance has 3.75 GB memory, ec2 micro instance has 1gb)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pom.xml to build your project

```
<properties>
  <spark.version>2.3.2</spark.version>
  <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
  <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>package.name.of.main.object</mainClass> <!-- add the path to file containing main method e.g com.company.code.ObjectName -->
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <!-- <phase>compile</phase> -->
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

in the directory containing the pom file run the command: `mvn clean install`, and your project would be made available as an uber/fat jar in the target directory.
You can then pass the JAR to spark-submit as usual.

Please keep the following points in mind:

1. Spark and Scala do not support Java 1.7. If you wish to use the
   latest Spark 2.x series, you have to use Scala 2.11/2.12 in your
   dependencies.
2. If you are using Spark 1.6, prefer using Scala 2.11, since the support 
   for Scala 2.10, would not be so readily available.